# What were the other steps on the execution checklist during Neptune Spear aka the killing of Bin Laden

Tags: military, assassination, cia

According to Wikipedia, capturing Bin Laden was step 7 on the execution checklist - what were the steps before? And were there any afterwards?

> The words of the commander on the ground were, "For God and country,
> Geronimo, Geronimo, Geronimo."[283] Officials subsequently explained
> that each step of the mission was labelled alphabetically in an
> "Execution Checklist", which is used to ensure all participants in a
> large operation are kept synchronized with a minimum of radio traffic.
> "Geronimo" indicated the raiders had reached step "G", the capture or
> killing of bin Laden.
> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Osama_bin_Laden

I assume, securing the data would be one, but that's just a speculation.